# github not showing last 9 commits

Tags: git, github

github showing 13th April's commit as my last commit. I just did `push` few minutes but its not showing up commits after `April 13` I can do `git log` and see commits that was made after April 13.

Comment: Is it on your primary branch? (by default, master). If not, did you switch the branch view on github?

Comment: Double check the branch you are on, git log will show up on your local. If you difference branch, you may needs `git push origin <branchname>`

Comment: Do others work on the repo with you? Maybe when you pushed it failed with a non fast forward error and you didnt notice. Try pulling then pushing again.

Comment: In addition to knowing what branch you were on, you should also state exactly what form of the "git push" command you used - e.g. did you add any additional arguments?

Comment: Its `master` branch and I've no other branch set. `master` is the only branch I've ever worked on. at the moment I am the only one working on it. and there was 9 `commit` and `push` after April 13 and none of these 9 is showing up.

Comment: Please post the output of these commands. 'git status' 'git push origin master'

Comment: `git status` returned `# On branch query/master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)` and `'git push origin master` returned `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: I also had the problem of commits not showing up after I had pushed, and it was just a GitHub hiccup. I'd just wait a while and see if your lost commits turn up after all :)

Comment: Is your head actually based on GitHub's head? Maybe you diverged somewhere before it.

Comment: I think Yes. How to check that ?

Comment: @x3ro: The same just happened to me - GitHub didn't show my commits after doing 2 commits and 2 pushes each. Just had to wait a couple of minutes for Github to show them. Stupid terrifying hiccup. 3 minutes of terror. :) Thanks for calming me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments, you're on a branch called `query/master`, which is slightly unusual.  Was creating that branch (`refs/heads/query/master`) deliberate?

In any case, the problem is as follows.  When you do:

```
git push origin master
```

... git assumes that you mean:

```
git push origin master:master
```

... i.e. "try to make the `master` branch in `origin` the same as my local `master` branch".  However, you're not on the local branch called `master` - you're on `query/master`.  Instead you need to do:

```
git push origin query/master:master
```

---

If what you really want is to start working on your `master` branch instead of `query/master`, then you can do the following:

```
# Check that the output of `git status` is clean, to make
# sure you don't lose any uncommitted work:
git status

# Switch to the master branch:
git checkout master

# Create a branch called old-master that records where master
# originally was, in case you still want that:
git branch old-master

# Reset your master branch to where query/master was:
git reset --hard refs/heads/query/master
```

Thereafter, when you're working on the `master` branch, `git push origin master` should do what you expect.

Comment: Oh! shit. few days ago I created a branch `query` but latter I removed that. but its still following it. so How would I switch to the default branch again ? and switch all these 9 commits back to the dafault branch ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: I've updated my answer with a suggested way of doing that.

Comment: @NeelBasu: I realised there was a mistake in the steps I suggested, which I've corrected now - apologies for that.

Comment: But I carried out the previous procedure and it apparently worked. So what I've missed ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: ah, I see why.  Originally I accidentally suggested renaming `master` to `old-master`, instead of just creating `old-master` based on it.  So I thought that `git checkout master` would fail - *however*, git has some "Do What I Mean" magic, so that if you checkout a branch `foo` that doesn't exist, and there's only one remote-tracking branch `refs/remotes/<something>/foo`, then it will create the branch `foo` that tracks the remote-tracking branch.  So `master` was recreated as it is should have been, and you could then reset it.