# Git add, git commit, git push not sending files to GitHub?

Tags: git

I am making changes on the code then performing the following, which looks like it goes through, but GitHub is not showing the commit?

```
git add .
git commit -m "Did something"
git push origin master

Response
=================================================
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Did you check to see if the commit was successful, i.e. you could access it from github? You may also want to consider the steps in this [SO Article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231928/github-not-showing-last-9-commits) to make sure your git status was 'clean' and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain  and now it works. Before running it I would type in the username and password manually and it would say I committed, but nothing ever showed up.

Thanks for the tip on pulling though!

Comment: Strange that github itself didn’t reply more info.